# How to replace words from a phrase in PHP?

Tags: php, str-replace

I have couple of mp3 files named `01 - Saanson Ko (Zid) - 128Kbps.mp3` and `01 - Saanson Ko (Zid) - 320Kbps.mp3`

I want it to be renamed to `01 - Saanson Ko (Zid) - Muzic.Asia`
I tried the following code but it did not work. How to do it?

```
$file = "01 - Saanson Ko (Zid) - 128Kbps.mp3";
$file = "01 - Saanson Ko (Zid) - 320Kbps.mp3";
$mp3_filename = str_replace(".mp3","",$file);
$mp3_filename = str_replace("128Kbps","Muzic.Asia",$file);
$mp3_filename = str_replace("320Kbps","Muzic.Asia",$file);
echo "$file";
```

Comment: if `-` char is fixed at the end, then without regex you  can do that with `substr("01 - Saanson Ko (Zid) - 128Kbps.mp3", 0, strrpos("01 - Saanson Ko (Zid) - 128Kbps.mp3", "-")).'- Muzic.Asia'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`str_replace()` returns the results.

Try these codes :

```
$file = "01 - Saanson Ko (Zid) - 128Kbps.mp3";
$file = "01 - Saanson Ko (Zid) - 320Kbps.mp3";
$file = str_replace(".mp3","",$file);
$file = str_replace("128Kbps","Muzic.Asia",$file);
$file = str_replace("320Kbps","Muzic.Asia",$file);
echo "$file";
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

You can use [`preg_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) and capture the parts which you want and replace it with `Muzic.Asia`, e.g.

```
$file = preg_replace("/ - \d+\w+\.\w+$/", " - Muzic.Asia", $file);
```

Comment: Using your code will replace `- Saanson Ko (Zid) - 128Kbps.mp3` as `-` is used at the beginning as well. Any solution to capture oly `- 128Kbps.mp3`?

Comment: @Macraze No, since I used the anchor: `$` this will only match at the end of a string